# Revel framework benchmarking http request dev vs prod

Tags: http, go, benchmarking, revel

I've deployed a web framework in Revel and in the last couple of times I've been benchmarking my development and production app and noticed a considerable difference of time for the same request.
My configs for both are the most simple possible, with the DB configuration as the only one I did.
For example, in dev mode I got for a request (worst case) ~40ms and in prod mode (worst case also) ~90ms.
How is that possible ?
Does revel, in prod mode, handles http requests differently ?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Is your dev environment served from localhost?

Comment: What is the method which you use to measure? Is there any webserver running along with the revel?

Comment: Both environments are served from localhost, with the purpose of testing. To measure I'm using apache benchmark (CLI). The configurations are the same. What changes is the run mode..

Comment: Can you paste your app.conf?

Comment: Here is the conf: http://www.codeshare.io/Oy5ip